# Why is my queryset only returning particular properties of my model instance in 'get' request?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Using django 1.11, I have a model with particular properties that I want to return with a get request(in my case get_queryset is returning a response to the get request), and it's only returning particular properties of a given model instance(a.k.a. object, a.k.a. record).
I want all the properties of the record, not just the ones django decides by default to give me using a queryset.

I've tried using—

```
ekg.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).values('user', 'id')
```

—to try to get particular values returned from the database to no avail.

Models:

```
class Ekg(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = False, null=False)

    ekgId               = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sampling_rate       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null = False, blank = False)
    dataTag2            = models.TextField(null = False, blank= False)
    dataTag3            = models.TextField(null = False, blank= False)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False) #date and time of the signal added to db
```

Views:

```
class EkgAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):

    permission_classes= [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes= [JSONWebTokenAuthentication]

    serializer_class        = EkgSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        #return all
        qs = Ekg.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).filter(ekgId=2).values('user', 'ekgId', 'sampling_rate', 'dataTag2', 'dataTag3', 'timestamp')
        return qs
```

Script that generates output(ignore jwt authentication, Response.text generates the output):

```
def do(method='get', data={}, is_json=True):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "JWT " + token} #authorization header required with jwt per restconfig/main.py JWT_AUTH configuration}
    if is_json:
        headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
        data = json.dumps(data)
    r = requests.request(method, EKG_ENDPOINT, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    print(r.status_code)#make sure its actually running
    return r



data = {

 }
do( data=data)
```

Output using api endpoint (not desired):

```
[{
    "sampling_rate":"212.00",
    "dataTag2":"anotherDatatag2",
    "dataTag3":"anotherDatatag3"
}]
```

Expected (timestamp not exactly that format, but sending me back something):

```
[{
    "ekgId":"2", 
    "timestamp":"July 10, 2019 - 22:19:47",
    "sampling_rate":"212.00",
    "dataTag2":"anotherDatatag2",
    "dataTag3":"anotherDatatag3"
}]
```

Comment: If you want all the fields returned you should not use `.values()`. What does your `EkgSerializer` look like?

Comment: The serializer setup fields were the issue thank you @IainShelvington